# Access fonts available in Pages.app in Preview.app in macOS

Tags: preview, pages, font

I am working on some designs which will also contain some styled text. I'd also add at this point that I am pretty novice with image editing and can do only basic stuff.

I am able to access some fonts in Pages.app which appears to be unavailable elsewhere in macOS and would like to use them in other apps, specifically Preview.app.

I worked through the prototype quickly in Pages.app and changed the font face to **Apple Chancery**, which I understand is built-in into Pages.app. (I come to this conclusion as I have not added any custom font into macOS after fresh installation).

However, I need the text in the form of an image with the background being transparent. To do that, I stated with a transparent PNG image, opened it in Preview.app and simply added a text box to type the text in.

However, I am unable to locate the said font which was available in Pages.app in Preview.app. This leads me to the conclusion that it's some font that's packaged with Pages.app and is not available systemwide. <strike>**I come to this conclusion as I was not able to locate the font in Font Book.app**</strike>. The font is visible in Font Book.app, but towards the bottom of the list.

I further experimented by downloading a custom font (TTF file) and installing it system wide. I was able to access the font everywhere, Font Book.app, Preview.app and Pages.app.

Is it possible to get access to the font that's available in Pages.app in Preview.app. If yes, how do I do it?

I have browsed through the entire bundle for Pages.app by running `ls -lR /Applications/Pages.app` but was unable to find anything matching the name. I understand that both the apps are Apple's first party app so there should be some way around.

I am using the current public release of macOS Mojave 10.14.3 (18D109) and Pages for macOS version 7.3 (5989).

Comment: I think Preview has less font access than other apps for some unknown reason.  There is another question here about that if I can find it....

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks for the reply. Yes, I was indeed able to find it in Font Book.app. May have missed the first time. Will edit the question. I am not able to locate it in Preview.app that leaves us with the question, how to use it with Preview.app

Comment: Re Preview app, see  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351349/edit-font-metadata-so-fontbook-will-put-it-in-english-smart-collection/351662#351662